# Session Start Then Session Off

Tags: php

Hi there I had some problem with my coding. Can you help me, the situation like this. I created one alert box that asks user if they want to exit from system. I want to do so if users want to logout press yes and the session will be terminated but if they press no the session will not be terminated. This was my coding:

```
     <?php
   session_start();
   session_destroy();

    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>

     <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Logout confirmation</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var userAns;

            userAns = confirm("Click OK to logout or CANCEL to stay at this page");
            if(!userAns) 

                window.location= "baseupdate1.php";
            else 

                window.location= "success.php";

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
      </html>
```

Can i ask something, my mini project had admin and user . If user login, it will direct to mainpage.php but if admin login it will go to admin.php. Admin.php can view user register, forms, and comments. I had used session to change button from sign up to userinfo at my header

```
     <strong><?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser'])){
      echo '<a href="userinfo.php">USER INFO</a>';
      }else
      echo '<a href="signup.php">SIGN UP';    
    ?> </strong>
```

Instead if has session the link will change, can i make if session admin login, will had no userinfo and signup but link admin info that had user register, forms, and comments. Sorry if my english not good. But i will try to make you all understand about it.

Comment: You should show the message before landing on a script with session_destroy();

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: you're mixing up server-side and client-side code. an easier solution would be to POST to the server to let it know the user wants to log off...

Comment: what do u mean by <?php session_start(); session_destroy();?> ?

Comment: Sorry I am new to php but like to love it, i want to do alert box that will ask user did they want to exit from system. When they press ok the system will exit, and i want the session will closed. Then if i pressed cancel it will stayed back to the page. And the session still can be used.

Answer (score 0):

**Set session during login**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = 'value';
```

**In your success.php page add this**

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
  unset($_SESSION['login']);
   session_destroy();
}
```

> I think it will help you.

Comment: thanks, successful..now i understand how to used it.